# WindowsAndroid: How to rotate the screen?

Tags: android

**Some background:**

I'm building a native app for Android using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, together with PhoneGap.

Currently, I'm running a WAMP server on Windows 8 machine, and I'm accessing the files on my local server through WindowsAndroid. All the components are styled using Fries v2 (an HTML/CSS design framework with a nice bunch of Android elements).

By firing up WindowsAndroid and accessing the files on my localhost sever, I'm able to get the look and feel of Android.

**Here's the issue:**

I can't seem to rotate the screen in WindowsAndroid. I've searched this issue and I was unable to find any results, only results on the other emulators out there.

**Question:**

How can I rotate the screen in WindowsAndroid?

Comment: From a quick-research, it seems that there is a screen rotation issue in Windroy (previously WindowsAndroid). Maybe you can [ask the developer of this app directly](http://www.socketeq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As you are a phonegap developer, you may not be sure about these details, so look for following:

Find out your main activity layout file. You'll find that under /res/layout  folder with .xml extension. Open the layout and look for field

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Change this to horizontal if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't start using PhoneGap yet. Currently I'm working in localhost, via WindowsAndroid. Any thoughts on flipping the orientation on that?